# R Markdown inline Code inside Latex math-environment

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr

short question, I've got this Code

````
```{r,include=F}
ct <- export2latex(createTable(compareGroups (grade ~ age , 
data = dat, max.ylev = 10, max.xlev = 20), show.p.overall = F,  show.all = TRUE, sd.type = 2))
````

and I'm using an inline code in R-markdown knitr like the following

```
$ `r ct` $
```

My problem now is that that I can't get rid of the dollar signs in my printed pdf which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9xog.png).

Does anybody know how to get rid of the dollar signs in my text?
Here is a MRE

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Author"
date: "24 2 2020"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(compareGroups)

n1 <- rnorm(10)
n2 <- rnorm(10,1,1)
dat <- data.frame(PID = 1:20,value = c(n1,n2), group = rep(1:2,each = 10))
ct <- export2latex(createTable(compareGroups (group ~ value, data = dat, max.ylev = 10, max.xlev = 20), show.p.overall = F,  show.all = TRUE, sd.type = 2))
````

Now here should be displayed the table one
$`r ct`$.
But the dollar signs are still in the document.
Seccond try with other math enviroment
`\(`r ct`\)`.

Comment: Do you *need* to add the dollar signs? I've never used 'export2latex` but at least with `xtable` there is no need to enter math mode

Comment: Unfortunately yes. export2Latex just translates the r table into latex syntax. I just tried xtable but it can't handle a compareGroups object.

Comment: If you provide a MRE I will give it a look..

Comment: Shot in the dark: it seems (based on limited information) that for whatever reason, when producing the .tex file the `$` character is getting resolved to `\$` (a printed dollar sign). Maybe try `\(` and `\)` to enter and exit math mode instead?

Comment: yeah seems like an appropriate way to handle this but it isn't working after all. Also ''\[ \]" isn't working.

Comment: sorry some trouble with syntax here. I meant \backslash[ `r ct` \backslash] which is also a math environment in Latex

Comment: What happens when you try using `\(...\)` or `\[...\]`? Does it just print those characters, like it did the dollar sign?

Comment: without the chunk in the middle it does what it supposed to do. It prints ...

Comment: It's not entirely clear from what you've posted, so I'll check just for completeness' sake: have you tried just omitting the dollar signs? It seems like they're just not doing anything here.

Comment: yes I only added them, because r studio told me to. Before I've used `results = asis`. But while compiling Latex complained because some parts of the code weren't inside the math environment. As you've tried it without the dollar signs, did it compile without complains?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work - couldn't install the packages because evidently my version of R is slightly outdated (and I'm not in a good position to upgrade it right now because of some active projects). Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: no problem and thanks for your try!